# How can I solve this problem in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

[image: How To Fix?]

How can I solve this problem in Visual Studio?
When I try to create a new class, it gives the same error

Answer (score 2):

Hum, I would suggest that you tap windows key, type in visual studio, and select run as administrator.

It looks like the folder/directory has/requires elevated rights.

So, then try this:

[image]

So, it looks like that folder was created - perhaps having run VS with Admin rights.

Try the above.

If not, check the folder - it should be a local drive folder.

A typical folder location for such project? NOT WHERE you have the project/folder now - it should not be in app data folder.

Typical folder location should look like this:

```
 C:\Users\Kalla\source\repos\ControlMISVBA
```

And inside of the above folder, then you can find/open the sln file, say like this:

[image]

Again, in above, note the folder location.

You need to move the location of your project folder to say my documents, or to the standard source->repos folder location.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Albert D. Kallal's suggestion, his analysis makes sense.

If his suggestions don't work for you, you can also try turning off the antivirus software on your computer and turning off the virus and threat protection settings and firewall in Windows Security Center.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-Community-access-denied-error-wh/10108969